# Is it possible to change from callback to a returning Promise for implementing an ErrorFirstCallback approach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, callback, backend

As describe in the documentation of Node.js an ErrorFirstCallback is trigger when the refer function fails. [Error-first-callbacks Node.js](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/errors.html#error-first-callbacks)

I'm practicing with this pattern of callbacks and I wonder if is it possible to refactor to a Promise approach, but I struggle with the implementation of it and how to retrive the result.

**This is the case scenario:**

- A function that transform a timeStamp value to an actual Date.
- If the parameter provided is not a number or not exist return the Reject promise with an Error Msg.
- If is fullfiel then return the result date.

The function looks like this:
`

```
function timeStampToDate(timeStamp, callback) {
  callback(
    (timeStamp) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (reject) {
          Error("Path for date not exist or undefined");
          return undefined;
        }
        if (resolve) {
          let stamp = timeStamp;
          stamp = new Date(stamp).toLocaleDateString("US-en", {
            year: "numeric",
            month: "2-digit",
            day: "2-digit",
          });
          if (/\d+/g.test(stamp)) {
            return stamp;
          }
        }
      }),
    timeStamp
  );
}
```

`

I higly appreaciate any suggestion if is an aproach commonly used with promises, or how to implement good practices regarding callbacks for error handling.

**The function that works in console :)**
`

```
const timeStamp = (timeStamp) => {
  // Original function
  if (!timeStamp || typeof timeStamp !== "number") return -1;

  let stamp = timeStamp;
  stamp = new Date(stamp).toLocaleDateString("US-en", {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "2-digit",
    day: "2-digit",
  });
  if (/\d+/g.test(stamp)) {
    return stamp;
  }

  return undefined;
}
```

`

Comment: a) you're not doing anything asynchronous here, so why use promises or callbacks at all? b) you want to transition away from callbacks towards promises, so why does your attempt still have (and use) a `callback` parameter?

Comment: `if (reject)`, `if (resolve)` does not work as you think it does

Comment: I totally agree Mr. Bergi, I haven't used the reject, or resolve functions as they should be. Some miss concepts about the promises functionality that I had. This study case was intended to translate the usual example with setTimeOut() that most courses provided. And if it was useful to implement a Promise directly to this.  
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

pleaes check if the below helps

```
function timeStampToDate(timeStamp) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (typeof timeStamp !== 'number' || !timeStamp) {
      reject(new Error('Invalid timeStamp parameter'));
    } else {
      const date = new Date(timeStamp);
      resolve(date);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Much appreciate Sr. brajesh, That's something that I was looking for. 
The real issue there was the reject(), resolve() functions, I was not sure how to implement them properly, but you help a lot. 